# Is it possible to insert a pair with a map type value into another map?

Tags: c++, stdmap

Tried looking this up but can't quite seem to find a detailed answer. Say I have a map:

```
std::map<int, string> categoryMap;
```

and I want to create a second map with keys and values that should only be accessed when associated with a specific key of the first map. The second map would also be similar:

```
std::map<int, string> itemMap;
```

I have attempted doing some sort of an insert function to try this out

```
categoryMap.insert(std::pair<int, map<int, string>>(itemValue, itemMap));
```

The error I receive claims that "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list." Is there another way to approach this or is this just not possible?

Comment: Shouldn't `itemName` be `itemMap`?

Comment: not really clear what you want to do. You can have a map of maps, but you cannot store a `map<int,string>` as value in a `map<int,string>`

Comment: please specify the declaration of categoryMap

Comment: over even better, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Right, fixed itemName to itemMap, however the problem still stands. So then if I wish to have a map of maps, would I have to do something like change `categoryMap` to `map<int, map> categoryMap`?

Comment: In c++ `>>` means write something from left to right (like `cin >> a;`), so when creating something like vector<vector<int> > make sure to have space between two >, it may cause the error.

Comment: we need to see the code and the full error message or a magic crystal ball ;)

Comment: @MishoTek that was fixed in c++11 already, you are now allowed to write `vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: @MishoTek: Did you travel to the present in a time machine? But you make a good point and that *could* be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but the type ([template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)) `int, map<int, string>` of the pair you are trying to insert does not match the map type `int, string`.

To be able to run your insert call:

```
categoryMap.insert(std::pair<int, map<int, string>>(itemValue, itemMap));
```

`categoryMap` has to be defined with the same template type as the item you are inserting, i.e.:

```
std::map<int, map<int, string>> categoryMap;
```

[See it online.](https://ideone.com/vnGrZ7)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::map<int, string>> categoryMap;
    std::map<int, std::string> itemMap;
    itemMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(1, "abc"));
    itemMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(2, "xyz"));
    categoryMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::map<int, std::string>>(1, itemMap));
}
```